# python regular expression appengine

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, seo

i have an application that uses appengine with python. Its a social network that maps places. I want to have each place in this kind or url: www.mysite.com/place/nameoftheplace

for that i did this regular expression as a parameter of mine WSGIApplication:

```
r'/place/(.*)'
```

and on the get requisition i have:

```
def get(self, placeName=""):
```

but for some reason, if i call www.mysite.com/place/theplace, it enters the get with placeName = "theplace" and after the get ends, it call itself over and over, with a diferent placename like "/css/something". Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using regular expressions?

Comment: do you have a better ideia so i can create redirect every /place/nameoftheplace to the same GET requisition?

Comment: @nightcracker Because that's the appropriate way to do this in the App Engine webapp framework?

Comment: How are regex'es appropriate when [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using relative URLs in your `<link rel-'stylesheet' href='css/something'>` tags in your HTML, so the browser is trying to fetch `/place/css/something`.

---

In your HTML, use, e.g., `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/static/something.css'>`, and in app.yaml use:

```
- url: /static/
  static_dir: static
```

then place your CSS in the static directory.

Comment: yes, you are right. How can i solve that? I have lots of relative URLs so its almost impossible to clear that out. Is there any other regular expression that can help me? Like if i take out the '/'. How can i make it? Thanks

Comment: @user469631 You'll simply have to find the relative URLs and prefix them with `/` - this is a bug in your markup.